# Datarow ItemArray doesn't work fine with a DataGridViewButtonColumn in first column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview with 3 columns. The fist one is a DataGridViewButtonColumn. The tow others are gathered from DB and I am populating my Datagridview from a datatable by using datarow.ItemArray.
Since the first column is a DataGridViewButtonColumn, the datagridview is being filled wring. The second column get the value of the third and the third is empty. Looks like the first column get the second value. I tried to add a null or empty value but it doesn't help

```
DataTable dtSelect = dataView.ToTable(true, "item", "subItem");

        foreach (DataRow datarow in dtSelect.Rows)
        {
              DGV.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, datarow.ItemArray });
        }
```

Now it is worst that before, the 2nd column get as value: System.Object[]

How can I use the item array to populate my Datagridview having a DatGridViewButtonColumn in the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you seriously considering the [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454332/datarow-itemarray-doesnt-work-fine-with-a-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-in-first-col/34454564#34454564). But if you insist, here is the answer to your original question. You need to allocate the appropriate `object[]`, copy the `ItemArray` into it (using the appropriate offset) and pass that array to the `Add` method, like this

```
var values = new object[DGV.Columns.Count];
foreach (DataRow datarow in dtSelect.Rows)
{
    datarow.ItemArray.CopyTo(values, 1);
    DGV.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the DataGridView.DataSource property directly with the DataTable and then create at runtime the DataGridViewButtonColumn. This column could be inserted at the position required

```
DataTable dtSelect = dataView.ToTable(true, "item", "subItem");
DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DGV.DataSource = dtSelect;

// Create the column and insert it as the first column
DataGridViewButtonColumn cl = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
cl.HeaderText = "Button column";
DGV.Columns.Insert(0, cl);

// Add the CellFormatting event to be able to change the button text
DGV.CellFormatting += DGV_CellFormatting;
.....


void DGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
       e.Value = "Click Me";
}
```